# Extending an existing layout in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout

I have my main application layout, but then I have an /account section of my site which has exactly the same layout as the application layout markupwise, except the /account pages have an added sidebar in the content area of the layout.

Rather than blatantly copy the application layout and create a nearly redundant "account" layout, I'd like to extend the application layout, adding the sidebar in the content area.

So I have something like this in my application layout:

```
<html>
<body>

<div id="content">

<%= yield %>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and I want

```
<html>
<body>

<div id="content">

  <div id="sidebar"></div>

  <%= yield %>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to accomplish this without copying code?

Answer (score 6):

You can have more than one `yield` in a layout, simply give the additional ones a name:

```
<html>
<body>
  <div id="content">
    <%= yield :sidebar %>
    <%= yield %>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can add HTML for that `yield` by using the `content_for` method

```
<% content_for :sidebar do -%>
  <div id="sidebar"></div>
<% end -%>
```

But you'll have to add that to every view you want to have a sidebar. Instead, create `views/layouts/application_with_sidebar.html.erb`

```
<% content_for :sidebar do -%>
  <div id="sidebar"></div>
<% end -%>

<%= render :file => 'layouts/application' %>
```

[Further reading](http://errtheblog.com/posts/26-content-for-whom)

If you'd prefer to keep the number of `yield`s to a minimum, you can nest your layouts instead.

**views/layouts/application.html.erb**

```
<html>
<body>
  <div id="content">
    <%= yield(:with_sidebar) or yield %>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**views/layouts/application_with_sidebar.html.erb**

```
<% content_for :with_sidebar do -%>
  <div id="sidebar"></div>
<% end -%>

<%= render :file => 'layouts/application' %>
```

**controllers/accounts_controller.rb**

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
  layout 'application_with_sidebar'
  ...
end
```

Comment: Then I'm throwing variables into the main, global layout that don't apply to all sections of the site. Just doesn't feel right. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: @Chad Nested Layouts like @mark suggested are probably the best alternative, then. It all depends on how often you need this markup to show up.

Answer (score 4):

Often you'll have the same situation for other parts of the site in which case it may make sense to use nested layouts.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-nested-layouts

Comment: Be sure to check out [later versions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.0.12/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-nested-layouts) of the same documentation. There were changes in newer versions of Rails and linked example may no longer work.

Answer (score 3):

If your /account route is bound to the account controller, you can always have a fullfeatured layout with conditional part like this

```
render :template => "/shared/sidebar" if controller.controller_name == "account"
```

(I have to admit that it does not please the eye though)